# While loop not exiting in my code

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, equals, do-while

I need my loop to end when i type "não" or "nao", but it never ends.

here's the code:

```
do {
        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro valor a ser trocado:");
        t1.setValor1(input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Digite o segundo valor a ser trocado:");
        t1.setValor2(input.nextInt());

        t1.trocarValores(t1.valor1, t1.valor2);
        System.out.println(t1);
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nVoce gostaria de trocar outro número? Digite 'sim' ou 'não'.");
        parar = input.nextLine();
    }while(!"não".equalsIgnoreCase(parar) || !"nao".equalsIgnoreCase(parar));
```

If i cut off the "(!"não".equalsIgnoreCase(parar)" and leave only the "!"nao".equalsIgnoreCase(parar)", it works, but i have no idea why ._.

Thanks everyone!

Well, looks like the problem is with the || and the "~" in my "não", so now, how do I fix the "~"? i want it to work with the exact "não". Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change

`while(!"não".equalsIgnoreCase(parar) || !"nao".equalsIgnoreCase(parar));`

to

`while(!"não".equalsIgnoreCase(parar) && !"nao".equalsIgnoreCase(parar));`

The opposite of `"não" or "nao"` is `not "não" and not "nao"`

Comment: It still doesn't work when i type "não", it only stops the loop if i type "nao" :/

Comment: may be is the 'ã' char your problem?

Comment: I tried puting "no" and it worked, so i'm guessing that's the problem, but now how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

while(!("não".equalsIgnoreCase(parar) || "nao".equalsIgnoreCase(parar)) );

Comment: It still doesn't work when i type "não", it only stops the loop if i type "nao" :/